# .net core console app - serilog write to bin/debug folder

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, serilog

i am using .net5 console app and set serilog to log to Logs/log.txt
but instead of write to rootFolder/Logs/log.txt
it write to bin/debug folder.

EDIT: I attach the code:

in the appsettings.json
it looks like this:

```
   {
      "Name": "File",
       "Args": {
        "path": "Logs\log.txt",
      }
   }
```

Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", true, true)
                .Build();
 
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging(builder => builder.AddSerilog(
                    new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                        .CreateLogger()))
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            var logger = serviceCollection.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();


            logger.LogInformation("hello from Serilog");
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
```

any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in program.cs file

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                        .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "MyApp")
                        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                    .WriteTo.File("Logs/log.log", 
                    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Hour)
                    .CreateLogger();
```

And appsettings file

```
 "Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}
```

},